# Probability of Sum of Independent Events Exceeding a Value

Tags: probability, soft-question

Suppose I have $n$ random number generators.  Once an hour, on the hour, each one generates a random real number $x_k$ such that $0 \le x_k \lt \infty$. Each generator produces its values according to its own independent probability distribution function $f_k()$, which is a known function.  For example, one generator might follow an exponential distribution, another might follow a normal distribution, etc.

Let $X = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k$ for all of the number generators in any one hour.

Given $y$ such that $0 \le y \lt 1$ (a probability), I need to find a value $z$ such that $P(X \le z) = y$.

Basically, I need to be able to do something like find the value that $X$ will be less than or equal to 50% of the time.

I apologize if I've gotten any of the notation wrong, I'm actually a software engineer so I know some things about math but not others.  I know enough about probability to express the problem above, but I don't even know where to begin in terms of solving it. Any help, or even suggested readings would be much appreciated.

Comment: The formalization was not so bad... :-) Unfortunately, I am afraid that at this level of generality, not much can be said.

Comment: Is there any bound to the $x_k$? $x_k\le ?$

Comment: @Did thanks for cleaning it up, and for your input.  I thought that might be the case.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra I've edited the question to reflect that there is no upper bound to the values for $x_k$. Realistically there is an upper bound for each generator, but they are all different and arbitrary.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: So as an (almost) software engineer myself, can you explain the context of why you have such generators and if you have a criteria of the number of different generators or indeed if they all fall into the special (ie named) distributions? Also Nice question btw :).

Comment: @Chinny84 Basically, the generators are clients on a network.  The numbers they generate represent the load they place on a service, and their probability distributions model the real world load profile (different clients interact with the service differently).  The $z$ I need to find to correspond to a given $y$ is how much capacity I need to make available to handle $y$% of the anticipated load without the client experience degrading.  Customers that use my product deploy this service on their own hardware, so I need a general solution to help them plan their capacity.

Comment: Beyond an iterative update of the prior distributions i.e. assume everything is uniform of normal for example, then update once more information is obtained of the possible distribution then you can do what you have said you wanted to do. The problem is, that setting the threshold too high is cost inefficient for you (presumably) and setting it too low will lead to degradation for your clients. But I think what I have just said you have pretty much gathered already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose they are all generating uniformly distributed random numbers in the closed interval $[a,b]$. Then your sum will never exceed $nb$ whereas that wouldn't be the case if they were generating normally distributed random numbers. The way you pose the question is way too generic. You need to be more specific about the distribution of each constituent random variable in your sum.

If $n$ is large, you can invoke the Central Limit Theorem. Your random variables don't have to be identically distributed (independence is sufficient). That way you only need to know the mean and variance of random variable in the sum to calculate probabilities since the sum will be approximately normal.

Comment: I've clarified the question concerning the distribution (each generator may have a different type of distribution).  I'm thinking there is no way to find a general solution to this problem, and I may wind up having to use simulations to approximate a result.

Comment: After doing a number of simulations, I'm finding that your suggestion of invoking the Central Limit Theorem is my best bet.  My $n$ will be in the hundreds, so modeling the sum as a normal distribution yields a very close fit.  Since what I need to do is estimate a value, that is close enough.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well for start, if the distribution are poissons, then also the sum of the variables will have poisson distribution, with the parameter equal to the sum of the parameters.

Otherwise (if $X_i$ admit densities $f_i$)  since they are independent then the random vector $Z = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ admits a density $f_Z (x_1, \dots , x_n) = f_1(x_1) \cdot \cdot \cdot  f_n(x_n)$

Then one can find the distribution of $X_1 + \dots + X_n$ applying Jacobi transformation formula with the function $g(x) = (x_1,x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}, x_1 + \dots + x_n)$

This way you can find the distribution of  $(X_1,X_2, \dots, X_{n-1}, X_1 + \dots + X_n)$ and you can calculate the marginal density (of the last element of the vector ) in the usual way.

That said, it is unlikely that you will be able to compute all those steps in a general case, because the calculations tend to become very difficult.

Comment: "if the distribution are exponentials then also the sum of the variables will have exponential distribution" Aaaargh...

Comment: @Did I'm so sorry! I got confused with the poisson distribution! I'll edit

Comment: I clarified the question, although I'm afraid that makes it even worse.  Since each generator could have a different type of distribution, I am thinking it might be impossible to come up with a general solution.

Comment: @AdamPlatt The latter solution does not assume the densities $f_1 \dots f_n$ to be the same. If you know that these random variables are independent and admit *densities* $f_1, \dots, f_n$, not necessarily equal, then you can apply the latter method (though its difficult in practice).